# How to list Git tags and messages using PHP?

Tags: php, git

I would like to list the last 10 tags with messages of git using php. Follow me in my examples:

**commiting something**

```
git commit -a -m 'hello world'
```

**creating a new tag**

```
git tag -a v.1.0 -m 'this new feauture show hello world'
```

Now in my application i just want to list the created tags, like:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Listing tags</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Last Tags</h1>
    <ul>
      <!-- I'm just assuming a situation, but this doesn't work -->
        <?php $tags = system('git tag --list'); ?>        
        <?php foreach($tags as $tag> : ?>
          <li><?php echo $tag['tag_name']; ?> - <?php echo $tag['msg']; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are a number of libraries available in composer that will give you a nice set of functions you can use to work with Git repos in your PHP code. Try [searching packagist for them](https://packagist.org/search/?q=git).

Comment: yeah man, i already have seen libraries that do this, in the future i'll u use surely. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. `git tag --list` doesn't include messages, use something like `git tag -n` instead
2. [`system()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) returns only the last line of the command output on success. It prints the rest of the output directly.

   If you want all of the lines as an array, utilize the 2nd argument of [`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

   ```
   exec('git tag -n', $tags);
   ```

Comment: @ShiraNail7 really the problem was a system function, u went direct in the point of the problem. I went to the php document to see these diferences, thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--format` option to control the format of the output.

For example, the following code fetches tag names and the commit subjects separated with a slash.

```
$cmd = "git tag --list --format='%(refname:strip=2)/%(contents:subject)'";

exec($cmd, $out, $exit_status);
if ($exit_status) {
    // command failed
}

foreach ($out as $line) {
    $pos = strpos($line, '/');
    $tag = substr($line, 0, $pos);
    $msg = substr($line, $pos + 1);
    echo "$tag - $msg\n";
}
```

Note, `%(refname:strip=2)` strips `refs/tags/` prefix from the part after `$GIT_DIR`.

Comment: Interesting @Ruslan Osmanov, i'll try it, tranks. About the git command to me is quiet, my doubt was around how to use php to list tags.

Comment: I tried what u told me, and work like a charm kkkkkk.  The biggest problem was, i was using the system command that has a lot difference with exec. So i went to the php document to see this. More one time, thanks.